# How to chain planners from JDBC Adapter SchemaFactory?

Tags: apache-calcite

I extended JDBC adapter and used a model.json configuration custom schema factory with 1 original schema and 2 derived schemas to add rules and that worked, rules got executed on original schema during planning, but their end-result didn't get chosen as the best option by the Volcano planner because it's too expensive. Rules transformed RelNode to execute on 2 derived schemas. More details below and in code.

1) Can I tell Volcano planner to ignore 1 out of 3 schemas that I passed through custom JDBC SchemaFactory?

I want the parser to work on that 1 original schema, but for the planner to never suggest an optimal (cheapest) plan in that schema (only other 2 derived schemas). 1 original schema is always mapped 1-to-1 with other 2 derived schemas, so the RelNode that my rule returns is always semantically equivalent, just more expensive (security reasons).

2) If that can't work, how can I call HepPlanner instead of default Volcano planner from SchemaFactory that is set in model.json, since that's my starting point?

You can find my entire code on GitHub, I made it publicly available so that everyone can have a better starting point with Calcite than I did.

Here is the link: https://github.com/igrgurina/multicloud_rewriter

Calcite library is amazing, but it's really hard to get into because it lacks examples and tutorials for common tasks.

Ideally, I would have HepPlanner execute my rules that transform them to semantically equivalent expressions that use 2 derived schemas instead of 1 original schema (I have a rule that does that), and then have Volcano planner optimize that using only 2 derived schemas, without having an idea that 1 original schema exists, due to security reasons.

I haven't found any reasonable examples that demonstrate how to do that so any help would be appreciated (please don't post links to Druid example, or Apache Calcite docs website, I went through them a thousand times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make this work by using `Hook.PROGRAM` and prepending my custom program that executes my rules before all others.

Since `Hook` is marked as `for testing and debugging only` in `Calcite` library, I would say this is not how it's supposed to be done, but I have nothing better at the moment.

Here is a short summary with code sample:

```
public static class MultiCloudHookManager {
    private static final Program PROGRAM = new MultiCloudProgram();

    private static Hook.Closeable globalProgramClosable;

    public static void addHook() {
        if (globalProgramClosable == null) {
            globalProgramClosable = Hook.PROGRAM.add(program());
        }
    }

    private static Consumer<Holder<Program>> program() {
        return prepend(PROGRAM);
    }

    // this doesn't have to be in the separate program
    private static Consumer<Holder<Program>> prepend(Program program) { 
        return (holder) -> {
            if (holder == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No program holder");
            }
            Program chain = holder.get();
            if (chain == null) {
                chain = Programs.standard();
            }
            holder.set(Programs.sequence(program, chain));
        };
    }
}
```

The `MultiCloudHookManager` is then used in `SchemaFactory`, where you simply call `MultiCloudHookManager.addHook()` method. In this case, `MultiCloudHookManager.PROGRAM` is set to `MultiCloudProgram`, that simply executes a set of rules in `HepPlanner`.

For full details, refer to [the source code in GitHub repository](https://github.com/igrgurina/multicloud_rewriter).

This hack solution is inspired by [another library](https://github.com/tzolov/calcite-sql-rewriter).